# NSRect rounded corners

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

Is there a simple way to add rounded corners to NSRect elements in Objective-C? Currently we're applying a PNG image that simulates corners to this:

```
NSRect newFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
```

But, performance becomes an issue because there are many instances of this NSRect along with the image being rendered with Core Animation. Perhaps rendering a native NSRect with rounded edges would be better from a performance standpoint? Do said edges look smooth (anti-aliased) when rendered with Core Animation?

Comment: NSRect draws an NS_RECT_angle.  Use an NSBézierPath.

Comment: @CodaFi: Even if we're planning to not use an image?

Comment: My bad, I have iOS-itis. I updated my comment.

Answer (score 4):

NSRect is a struct containing an NSPoint and an NSSize, so I think you mean anything that accepts NSRects (so subclasses of NSView).  All NSView subclass layers respond appropriately to -cornerRadius (except something about NSScrollView).

```
self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

Comment: @Zakman - don't forget to add `CoreGraphics` framework to your project.

Comment: Great, I'll give this a shot thanks! Just out of curiosity do you think Core Animation will render a masked NSRect more efficiently than an NSImage (as we currently have it) when there's 20-30 instances? We're hoping by natively rendering the NSRect it will increase the framerate...

Comment: That's what a CALayer is, anyhow!